GET response truncated with Jersey 3.1.9 on tomcat 11.0.1
Recently I have attempted to upgrade from Tomcat 10.1.x to tomcat 11.0.1.  I have noticed a problem where my html responses are being truncated to a length of around 20KB.
I have managed to reproduce it using a simple test app with the following resource:
@Path("/l")
public class Lorum {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable doGet() throws IOException {
        return new Viewable("/index.jsp", Map.of());
    }
}

index.jsp simply contains a large lump of HTML (1000 lines of approx 500 characters which I created from a text generator on the web.
I find that part of the response is displayed in the browser and if I view source the content has been cut short.
I have not been able to reproduce this problem with tomcat 10.1.x.  Likewise I have been unable to reproduce it with a simple servlet that does not use Jersey.  Thirdly, I am unable to reproduce it if I change the above code to return a String from a file read from the classpath rather than returning a Viewable:
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String doGet() throws IOException {
        return getResourceFileAsString("/lorum.html");
    }

Has anyone seen anything similar?  I'm not really clear whether the problem or misconfiguration is with Tomcat or Jersey as it is the specific combination that exhibits it.  It is also nothing to do with SSL as I see the same thing over unencrypted http.
